# Could not find a registry key with name "AspNetMvc4VS11" under "Software\NuGet\Repository"

Tags: templates, c#-4.0, durandal, single-page-application, visual-studio-2013

I am getting the following exception when I try to create a new project by using Durandal template in VS 2013.

```
New-->Project-->Web--> ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application --> Durandal SPA Project

The Project template has a reference to a missing Registry value. Could not find a registry key with name "AspNetMvc4VS11" under "Software\NuGet\Repository"
```

Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[follow this instruction](https://docs.nuget.org/create/packages-in-visual-studio-templates)

Go to registry and find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\NuGet\Repository

Copy a file path from other's name.
Create a registry string for 'AspNetMvc4VS11' and paste the path.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by installing vs2012. After this i configured a new mvc4 project on vs2013  using the  Durandal template.